# Installed Mariadb - now mysql gives error Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had a perfectly working instance of Mysql server, then installed Mariadb-server.

Now running the command

> mysql -v

gives the error

> ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded

Incase it may help, I left password field blank during installation of Mariadb server.

Would really appreciate some help on this, pls.

Answer (score 3):

As you upgraded from MySQL to MariaDB your original configuration is probably still in place instead of the default MariaDB configuration file.

Adding

plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so

to the [mysqld] section should fix the authentication issue for localhost connections.

https://websiteforstudents.com/fix-mariadb-plugin-unix_socket-is-not-loaded-error-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/